# PHP - Unexpected Else On Line 33 and 32

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a panel for my game server and i am trying to make it check for an existing user_id in the punishments table so that it can only be banned once.

I tried on another server.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "asta";
$dbpassword = "*******";
$dbname = "asta";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_error()){
die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
. mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{

$userid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userid');
$reason = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'reason');
$duration = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'duration');


$sql = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `punishments` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows >= 1) {
    echo "The user with userid '$userid' is already banned.";
} else {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO punishments (user_id, reason, duration, origin_id, type, time, active)
values ('$userid','$reason','$duration','10','2','1','1')";
if ($conn->query($sql)){
echo "The user with userid '$userid' has been banned!";
}
else{
echo "Error: ". $sql ."
". $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}
}
else{
echo "REASON should not be empty";
die();
}
}
else{
echo "USERID should not be empty";
die();
}


}

}
?>
```

I expected it to handle the http request

Comment: You have two `else` statements that don't appear to have a corresponding `if` conditional; the `else` for `REASON should not be empty` and `USERID should not be empty`. Did you mean to use an `else if` to check that those specific conditions were supplied? As it stands, only your `Error` `else` is chained to your `$conn->query($sql)`.

Comment: I forgot to add $reason and $duration .. now i only have one error unexpected else on line 36

Comment: If you indent your code, it will help you will see where you have missed elses and orphan } etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code has many errors:

Miss `if` code check `!empty` for `$reason`, `$userid` variables

Then I add them into code:

```
<?php
$host       = "localhost";
$dbusername = "asta";
$dbpassword = "*****";
$dbname     = "asta";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {

  $userid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userid');
  $reason = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'reason');
  $duration = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'duration');
  if (!empty($userid)) {
    if (!empty($reason)) {
        $sql    = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `punishments` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
            echo "The user with userid '$userid' is already banned.";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO punishments (user_id, reason, duration, origin_id, type, time, active) values ('$userid','$reason','$duration','10','2','1','1')";
            if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                echo "The user with userid '$userid' has been banned!";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . $conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    } else {
        echo "REASON should not be empty";
        die();
    }
  } else {
    echo "USERID should not be empty";
    die();
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: You should using some IDE to validate syntax code. Ex: Phpstorm

Comment: Do you know why my html form is submitting '0' instead of NULL into the database?

Comment: @AstaTM I suggest you make a new question and provide your form code and what is actually being set to '0'. A column name would be nice...